# Merging multiple different worksheets into master template with weird formatting

Tags: vba, excel

This might seem a bit complicated, so let me know if I need to be more clear.

I receive ~20 reports from one department and I am in charge of consolidating data from a specific worksheet in each report into one master file. All the reports are the exact same and the data ranges are pretty much set. I am relatively new to VBA, but I was able to piece together a code through research to copy and paste all the data into a new workbook using a loop. It would, however, be ideal if I could put this data directly into the report template. This is where I need help. The formatting of the template is not ideal - my headers don't start until A25 and there's a totals tab and instructions on the bottom so I can't just put the values in the last empty row.

I would like to figure out how to ensure that the data from the first worksheet I pull from gets put in A26 and the data from the following worksheets get put in the next available cell.

Below is the code I currently have. I understand generally what things mean, but just keep in mind I'm a VBA noob... so be nice :)

```
Sub MergeData()

Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String, FolderPath As String
Dim LastCell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
End With

FolderPath = "C:\Desktop" 'changed for privacy
FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

Do While FileName <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        Worksheets("SBP WIP").Range("A26:AK336").Copy
        LastCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ActiveCell.Copy

        .Close False

    End With
    FileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your first With-End With block just add one line

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A25").Value = "X" ‘ make sure to hit row 25 in subsequent “xlUps”
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
End With
```

And before macro ending add:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A25").ClearContents
```

Comment: The data is still pasted at the very bottom of the template, after the totals row and instructions. I understand the logic, but it's still finding the very last value in the worksheet rather than the X in row 25

Comment: See edited answer: I added a missing dot (`.`) right before `Range("A25")`, which makes it a child of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. If this solves your question you may consider marking the answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: Row 25 already has headers, but even when I change the value to X, the data I want still gets pasted to the very bottom of the template.